# unix extract lines from file and combine

Tags: bash, unix, recursion, line, extract

I have 10 files. Each file contains multiple lines but I'm interested in 2 specific lines.

Let's say the format of the 2 lines is:

```
test1_hello
test2_world
```

The second file contains:

```
test1_hallo
test2_germany
```

What I want to do is to recursivley run over the files and extract the
relevant strings from each file to one main file.

So the final result contents of final_file would be :

```
helloworld
hallogermany
```

Is this possible in a one line command in Bash?

Comment: Using bash, csh or something equivalent? Or using a programming language (c++, python, etc..)???
Your question is not really good. If you want to write a linux script, then you should write on the right Q&A

Comment: Hו Dave , my main goal is to send a bash command over ssh and finally retrive the final result file that contains all the combined strings

Comment: It's best to show us that you've given this some work yourself. Where have you got to so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might be close to what you're looking for:

```
for f in * ; do sed 's#[^_]*_##' $f | tr -d '\n' ; echo ; done
```

`sed` will remove the part before the first `_` (including that `_`) by **s**ubstituting the regular expression `[^_]*_` by an empty string, and `tr` will remove the newline chars (`\n`). With your example:

```
$ cat f1
test1_hello
test2_world
$ cat f2
test1_hallo
test2_germany
$ for f in * ; do sed 's#[^_]*_##' $f | tr -d '\n' ; echo ; done
helloworld
hallogermany
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in $(ls -1); do grep ^test* $file | awk -F'_' '{print $2}' >> myfile;done
```

Comment: Ferdy , the output from this command is each word in a new line .